# Unable to start tomcat 8.0.39

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using **Eclipse Mars** IDE, JRE **1.8.0_51**, and **Tomcat 8.0.39**. Is there any compatibility issue? Please suggest.

> Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

I have also tried increasing the timeouts, but it didn't work.

> Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          Nov 9 2016 08:48:39 UTC Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   number:         8.0.39.0 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 7 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            6.1 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_51-b16 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\esboddu.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:
>   D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.39 Dec
>   12, 2016 8:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
>   log INFO: Command line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\esboddu.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.home=D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\esboddu.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.39-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\endorsed
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: The
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Informatica\9.6.1\clients\tools\datadirect;C:\app\esboddu\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\app\esboddu\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;D:\hadoop-home\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre;C:\Users\esboddu\AppData\Local\Programs\EmEditor;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;D:\softwares\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 464 ms Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Dec 12, 2016 8:27:23 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\esboddu.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\will.xml
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:will' did not find a matching property.
>   Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDescriptor INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor
>   C:\Users\esboddu.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\will.xml
>   has finished in 49 ms Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Dec 12, 2016 8:27:24 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 375
>   ms

Comment: Eclipse Mars EE and later have native support for Tomcat 8, please post your stacktrace if you note an error on server start.

Comment: It seems that the server has been started: 'Server startup in 375 ms' How do you check that the serves has not started? Are you working with the embedded Tomcat of Eclipse or with the standalone version?

Comment: The minimun Java version required is Java 7 as you can see at Tomcat Site, so it seems not to be a versions problem (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)